# How to the get method or function adress which launched a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I want to get the address or name of the function/method which run a thread identified by its thread id.

How can I do that with windows API ?  I am using win7 x64.
My tries to look for doc in windows api failed ...

Comment: I have a feeling that information is not stored anywhere - in a debugger [or suffiicently competent process viewer], you can probably drill down the stack until you find the first call, but other than that, the "original thread starting address" is not stored [it certainly isn't in any thread library code that I'm familiar with]

Comment: Of course, if it's YOUR software, you can always wrap a std::thread into another object that contains the extra information...

Comment: Keeping track is messy.  Whatever container is used to store the name/threadId mapping would need a lock so that insertions/ deletions upon thread create/terminate could be performed safely.  The lock would have to be mintained while, say iterating.  There is danger of stale information being returned.  I would try very hard to not do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Like I said, walk the stack and you will eventually find the call to the MS provided thread-creation function which calls the thread start function. But there is no publicly available API for this, you have to reverse engineer or instrument the CreateThread call.

Comment: Function names are not even preserved in executables (except in debug builds) so you're asking for the impossible. Write your own CreateThread wrapper which takes a string to associate with the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement this functionality as the Windows API does not provide it.